# SPARQL query on Pizza ontology

Tags: sparql

I am a beginner in SPARQL. I have the [pizza ontology](http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#) and i'm trying to write a query that lists all hot toppings. So far I've come up with this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT ?targetPizza
WHERE {
?topping rdfs:subClassOf pizza:PizzaTopping .
?topping rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasSpiciness .
?restriction owl:someValuesFrom pizza:Hot .

}
```

However, it returns an empty result. Why is my query wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And why do you select `?targetPizza` instead of the `?topping` variable?

Comment: I thought the the choice of variable doesn't make much difference. And shouldn't return all pizzas with hot topping? But even when i change it to topping it is still an empty result.

Comment: "The choice of variable doesn't make a difference"? You SELECT the variable `?targetPizza` which is not bound in the query. Why do you assume that this doesn't matter?

Comment: Previously i tried to exchange PizzaTopping with VegatableTopping and i put Mild instead of Hot and the querry worked. But i don't know if it's applicable in all cases.

Comment: See my answer below, it explains why it doesn't work for hot spicy toppings - the reason is, that the Pizza ontology data is the heterogeneous modeling even for toppings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: There is nothing that matches your query. You can see everything that would match your query structure without the given spiciness value by running

```sql
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT * WHERE {
  ?topping rdfs:subClassOf pizza:PizzaTopping .
  ?topping rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
  ?restriction rdf:type owl:Restriction .
  ?restriction ?p ?o .
}
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      topping       |          p          |          o          |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  pizza:FishTopping |  rdf:type           |  owl:Restriction    |
|  pizza:FishTopping |  owl:onProperty     |  pizza:hasSpiciness |
|  pizza:FishTopping |  owl:someValuesFrom |  pizza:Mild         |
|  pizza:NutTopping  |  rdf:type           |  owl:Restriction    |
|  pizza:NutTopping  |  owl:onProperty     |  pizza:hasSpiciness |
|  pizza:NutTopping  |  owl:someValuesFrom |  pizza:Mild         |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So what's the problem here? Next step would be to go the other way around, i.e. we check for everything that is related to hot spiciness:

```sql
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {
  ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
  ?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasSpiciness .
  ?restriction owl:someValuesFrom pizza:Hot .
}
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------+
|              s               |
+------------------------------+
|  pizza:HotGreenPepperTopping |
|  pizza:JalapenoPepperTopping |
|  pizza:TobascoPepperSauce    |
|  pizza:CajunSpiceTopping     |
|  pizza:HotSpicedBeefTopping  |
+------------------------------+
```

So, how can this be? Well, the short answer is, none of the spicy toppings is defined as instance of the class `pizza:PizzaTopping`, you can validate this with an additional OPTIONAL triple pattern

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT distinct ?s ?type WHERE {
  ?s rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
  ?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasSpiciness .
  ?restriction owl:someValuesFrom pizza:Hot .
  OPTIONAL {?s rdf:type ?type }
}
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------+------------+
|              s               |    type    |
+------------------------------+------------+
|  pizza:HotGreenPepperTopping |  owl:Class |
|  pizza:JalapenoPepperTopping |  owl:Class |
|  pizza:TobascoPepperSauce    |  owl:Class |
|  pizza:CajunSpiceTopping     |  owl:Class |
|  pizza:HotSpicedBeefTopping  |  owl:Class |
+------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to select ALL subclasses of Pizza Topping, then you're query should work properly :

```
SELECT ?targetPizza
WHERE {
?targetPizza rdfs:subClassOf* pizza:PizzaTopping .
?targetPizza rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasSpiciness .
?restriction owl:someValuesFrom pizza:Hot .
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ?targetPizza
WHERE {
?targetPizza rdfs:subClassOf pizza:PizzaTopping .
?targetPizza rdfs:subClassOf ?restriction .
?restriction owl:onProperty pizza:hasSpiciness .
?restriction owl:someValuesFrom pizza:Hot .

}
```